# Perl web application issue: DBI connect failed: Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)

Tags: mysql, apache, perl, tcp

I have issue with my Perl web application, running on Apache 2.2 on Windows 2008r2 with separated MySQL database on CentOS server.

Here is the issue: I'm getting timeouts periodically with error:

```
DBI connect('host=10.148.xxx.xxx:database=XXX','root',...) failed: Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)
```

When I say periodically, that means that most of the time everything works as expected, but from time to time I get this message and it causes my application to throw error page.

I've search a lot on internet and found couple of recommended solutions which didn't work for me.

First, I thought that my database server is unreachable but using MySQL enterprise monitor I found out that wasn't the case.

Then I thought that I might have ran out of TCP ports so I've increased the number of ephemeral ports and decreased the timeout period as described in this post:
http://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/6956/how-to-tune-the-tcp-ip-stack-for-high-volume-of-web-requests/

In short I did this:

> Reduce the TIME_WAIT by setting the TcpTimedWaitDelay TCP/IP parameter to 30 seconds on the windows registry key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters, as a DWORD value.
>
> Increase the range of ephemeral ports by setting the dynamicportrange to an higher value through the command netsh int ipv4 set dynamicportrange tcp start=32767 num=32768, this will set the port range from 32768 to 65535."

But no luck, still getting timeouts

Next, I've updated my Apache config file with these parameters to further decrease `KeepAliveTimeout`:

```
Timeout 100
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

Still, no luck.

My main problem is that everything is working most of the time, and I'm even having trouble reproducing the issue, but it is coming up on daily basis and my clients are getting annoyed.

I'm not even sure in which direction to go, is it MySQL, is it Perl DBI module issue, is it Apache, is it TCP/IP configuration, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you found an answer provided here helpful, please upvote and/or mark as accepted, so that other users with a similar question can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a separate issue that is manifesting in the symptom of "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)".

Unless you're turning around a huge amount of very fast connections you'll not need to edit the ephemeral ports or timeouts. By doing this, you're just putting off the cause to happen later.

I would check that your application (in its entirety) is closing connections when it's done with them? That includes database connection, client http sockets, file/directory handles, etc... Use "netstat" to monitor what ports/connections are currently open when your application is running. Find out what's ever increasing, then track down in your app (or some other app that's also running on the same machine) what's causing these kinds of connections. You can then take action to close the connections correctly, solving your problem.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Nestat is showing small amount of active connections, and that's why I really don't think it TCP exhaustion that's causing this issue. I had couple of .Net windows services on the same machine but I've moved them to another box.

Comment: Here is the output of netsh: C:\>netsh int ipv4 show tcpstats
MIB-II TCP Statistics
------------------------------------------------------
Timeout Algorithm:  Van Jacobson's Algorithm
Minimum Timeout:   10
Maximum Timeout:                    4294967295
Maximum Connections: Dynamic
Active Opens:999295
Passive Opens:71886
Attempts Failed:2
Established Resets: 2162
Currently Established:              21
In Segments: 75634810
Out Segments: 81423272
Retransmitted Segments: 143915
In Errors:  0
Out Resets: 8732

Comment: This 'Active Opens' parameter confused me, because it looks like that's the number of active TCP connections, but it really isn't. To my understanding, this is number of connections from last reboot or something like that.